# Javascript AND statement syntax

Tags: javascript, forms, syntax

I'm trying to do a simple form validation for a range of user input values (-180 to 180) but code is not behaving as I expected.

```
function validateForm()
{
retVal = true;

lon = document.getElementById("LON").value;
if ((lon  >= -180 && lat <= 180 )== false) 
retVal=false;

if(retVal == false)
{

alert('Please correct the errors');
return false;
}
return retVal;
}
```

So if I enter a value of -254 for example I get the alert as expected.
However if I enter anything greater than -181 I do not get the alert.
What am I missing here??

Warning: I'm a newbie.

Comment: that `== false` makes no sense. Change the logic so you do not need that weird check.

Comment: Please format your code before posting

Comment: It does make sense, @epascarello - the result of both the subexpressions around the `&&` are boolean. (I wouldn't code it that way, but it's not "wrong".

Comment: where do you get `lat`?

Comment: your `if()` is checking `lon` for one part of the check and `lat` for the other... did you intend to use `lon` for both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should check `lon` variable for being not less than `-180` and not more than `180`. Use that simple `if` statement:

```
var lon = document.getElementById("LON").value;
if (lon < -180 || lon > 180)
    retVal = false;
```

It is important to note, that you'd better define local variables using `var` keyword.

Comment: @VisioN Tried your 'if' statement. However it still only catches the out of range minus value

Comment: @DarraghO'Keeffe Do you use `lon` variable in both parts?

Comment: @VisioN I believe so                                             `lon = document.getElementById("LON").value;`

Comment: @VisioN Thanks just caught the `lat` and  `lon` in your statement. Working now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need that `if()` at all -- just set `retval` to the boolean value from the expression...

```
function validateForm() {
    var lon = document.getElementById("LON").value;
    var retval = (lon  >= 180 || lon <= -180);
    if(!retVal) { alert('Please correct the errors'); }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the initialised 'lon' but where is 'lat' being initialised?

the following should work:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var lon = document.getElementById("LON").value;        
    var lat = document.getElementById("LAT").value;

    var isValid = (lon  >= -180 && lat <= 180 );

    if ( !isValid)        
    {
        alert('Please correct the errors');
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Yes that was it, just didn't catch the `lat` initially

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate on some range then the if condition should be checking for a single variable only, if true, return true, else display the error and return false.

```
function validateForm()
{
    retVal = true;

    lon = document.getElementById("LON").value;
    if (lon  >= -180 && lon <= 180) 
    {
    return retVal;
    }
    else
    {
    alert('Please correct the errors');
    retVal = false;
    return retVal;
    }
}
```